# Changing HTML in Google Inspector

Tags: security, google-chrome, web-inspector

I know it's very possible to open up Google Inspect Element and change the HTML, CSS, or whatever for any given site.

My question though, is couldn't this really be a security threat? Or at least a threat to the integrity of your website. Say you had a website done in PHP, and in a script you were expecting POST from a form, however someone opened up your site in Inspect Element, and changed the form to GET. Your site wouldn't function properly, correct?

I have to imagine some hacker-savy hooligan could do some damage with this, could they not? I am not hack-savy myself so I don't know what they could do, but I have to imagine the worst.

So is this yet another thing we should consider when developing websites? How people may alter the HTML? I mean, I understand the need to like strip tags and all that to protect your site from malicious user input, but having to worry about how they could actually change the site right in front of their eyes is a bit ridiculous.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope,  this is **never** a security threat.  Not in the slightest.  A real hacker is going to use [BURP](http://www.portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html) (or a similar proxy) to exploit shitty web applications,  this is generally easier than modifying the HTML of JavaScript.

Being able to modify client side scripts is obvious,  thats not the threat.  The the threat is only created when a naive developer is relying upon these controls for security,  in this industry we call this a [CWE-602](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/602.html) violation.  You can never trust the client, that is the foundation of web application security.   **All security related controls must be server side.**